# How can I change the state of arrays using hooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I don't know exactly what it is, but I have run into countless problems in trying to do the simplest state updates on arrays using hooks.

The only thing that I have found to work is using the useReducer to perform a single update on the array with putting dispatch on onClick handlers.  In my current project, I am trying to update array state in a for loop nested in a function that runs on a form submit.  I have tried many different solutions, and this is just one of my attempts.

```
  function sessionToState(session) {
    let formattedArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < session.length; i++) {
      formattedArray.push({ url: session[i] })
      setLinksArray([...linksArray, formattedArray[i]])
    }
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        method="post"
        onSubmit={async e => {
          e.preventDefault()

          const session = await getURLs({ populate: true })

          sessionToState(session)

          await createGroup()
```

I was wondering if there are any big things that I am missing, or maybe some great tips and tricks on how to work with arrays using hooks.  If any more information is needed don't hesitate to ask.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if there are any big things that I am missing

TLDR: `setLinksArray` does not update `linksArray` in the current render, but in the next render.

---

Assuming the variables are initialized as follows:

```
const [linksArray, setLinksArray] = useState([])
```

A hint is in the `const` keyword, `linksArray` is a **constant** within 1 render (and this fact wouldn't change with `let`, because it's just how `useState` works).

The idea of `setLinksArray()` is to make a different constant value **in the next render**.

So the `for` loop would be similar to:

```
setLinksArray([...[], session0])
setLinksArray([...[], session1])
setLinksArray([...[], session2])
```

and you would get `linksArray = [session2]` in the next render.

Best way to keep sane would be to call any `setState` function only once per state per render (you can have multiple states though), smallest change to your code:

```
function sessionToState(session) {
  let formattedArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < session.length; i++) {
    formattedArray.push({ url: session[i] })
  }
  setLinksArray(formattedArray)
}
```

Furthermore, if you need to perform a side effect (like an API call) after all `setState` functions do their jobs, i.e. after the NEXT render, you would need `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...do something with updated linksArray...
}, [linksArray])
```

For a deep dive, see https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime

Comment: I feel much clearer now on what is happening behind the scenes, which I feel is what gave me most of my trouble.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

When invoking state setter from nested function calls you should use [functional update form of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). In your case it would be:

```
setLinksArray(linksArray => [...linksArray, formattedArray[i]])
```

It is not exactly clear what kind of problems you encounter, but the fix above will save you from unexpected state of `linksArray`.

Also this applies to any state, not only arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Performance wise you shouldn't call `setState` every iteration. You should set state with final array.

```
const sessionToState = (session) => {
  setLinksArray(
   session.map(sessionItem => ({url: sessionItem}))
  );
}
```

... or if you want to keep old items too you should do it with function inside setState ...

```
const sessionToState = (session) => {
  setLinksArray(oldState => [
   ...oldState,
   ...session.map(sessionItem => ({url: sessionItem}))
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I ended up using useReducer to test some things out, and I realized that there seem to be issues with editing the state on the onSubmit.  How would I go about delaying the submit until the state is updated, or is there a different strategy?  Right now I am testing it by having a seperate button to perform the state update, and then when I click the submit the state is correct when sent to the server.